# How can I get the path for the conda package after conda build

Tags: conda, conda-build

I am trying to automatize conda build process within a makefile. I build a conda package with the following command.

```
conda build . --output-folder dist/conda
```

A file `foo-1.0.0-0.tar.bz2` is created under `dist/conda/linux-64`. Next, I want to do some extra stuff on that file. But I don't know the exact path, because package name, version, build number and platform can change.

How can I achieve this within a Makefile? I've tried some [environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/source/environment-variables.html) created during conda build but it seems that they are only available during the build time.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Running `conda build . --output-folder dist/conda --output` will output

> dist/conda/noarch/my-tool-0.34.0a0-gab8df4f.conda